# Change of activity with the slide of the finger

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder how to change the activity with the slide of the finger, or slide your finger from right to left and change the activity, the way we saw the pictures on smartphones.

Anyone know?

Cumpz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the following link

http://savagelook.com/blog/android/swipes-or-flings-for-navigation-in-android

Comment: There is no need to use this kind of approach, a viewpager (present in the compatibility package ) would provide the same effect while using newer concepts like fragments, which may ease the transition of an app to a new form factor.

Comment: Chrome says that the website contains malware.

Comment: Even Safari also says that the website contains malware. **Don't click on above Link it's Unsafe** it redirected me to Adult Content.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote a demo at https://github.com/chenjishi/SlideActivity, all you need to do is extend the SlidingActivity in the project and you get a slide effect,here is the screenshot:
[image]

#### old method

1.make the activity transparent

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/activityAnimation</item>
</style>
```

2.use SlidingPaneLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/slide_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_gravity="left"/>
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#E6E6E6"
        android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

3.so here you get you want
[image]

you can slide with your finger to move the activity, and you also can destroy it when sliding to the right most of screen.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more on how you did it? Looking for the same behavior in our app. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a **ViewPager** to achieve what you are looking for. Here is [a tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537).

Answer (score 0):

its the "pager" implementation provided in the Android 4.0 / 3.0.
In the earlier versions you can implement it using the compatibility package of Android.
Uses Fragments to implemet it.
You can find the demo project in the SDK itself.