# How can i use a button to open an xml file in my project

Tags: android, xml

I want to open an xml file in my project on button click this is my code could somebody please suggest me how can i do it. I'm unable to do it the one i did was using onclicklistener. Also  how can i make the second fragment the default fragment so that when i slide from left to right i can view the first fragment.

```
public class FragmentFirstPage extends Fragment {

View root;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle){

    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page1, container, false);

            //If you want to retrieve a textview inside fragment_page1.xml for example, you shall do:
            //TextView text = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.blablabla); 


    Button bt = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1);

  //  final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.activity_main_viewpager);

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
          public void onClick (View v){
             Intent i=new Intent(fragment_page1.this, SplashActivity.class);
             startActivity(i);

         } 
    });
    return root;
}
```

Gives me error at 
Intent i=new Intent(fragment_page1.this, SplashActivity.class);
says fragment_page1 cannot be resolved to a type or else

Intent i=new Intent(FragmentFirstPage.this, SplashActivity.class);
says Multiple markers at this line
    - The constructor Intent(FragmentFirstPage, Class) is 
     undefined

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Please add the logs

Comment: I don't see you trying to open an XML file anywhere.  Do you mean display another activity?  Or display another fragment?  Render a layout? Please be precise in your questions.

Comment: I'm tryin to open it from an xml layout is it possible to do?

Comment: The main xml life is
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Proceede"
            android:onClick="@layout/main" 
            />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FragmentB fragmentB = new FragmentB();
FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, customerFragment).commit();
```

write this in your onClick method for navigating from FragmentA to navigate to FragmentB.

Answer (score 0):

You have FragmentFirstPage and FragmentSecondPage, you may have fragment_page1.xml and fragment_page2.xml

PS: remove any android:onClick attribute

Inside your FirstFragmentPage, on onCreateView (), , add the following if your button is on fragment_page1.xml

```
Button bt = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);

ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.your_viewpager_id ();

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener (){

     @Override
      public void onClick (View v){

      viewPager.setCurrentItem (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1); //or -1 to go previous

      } 

}
```

Forgive my code format, I'm typing from my smartphone : /

Comment: Never mind the format it gave me 3 errors
1.ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById (R.id.your_viewpager_id ();
says The method your_viewpager_id() is undefined for the type R.id
2. bt.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener ()
View.onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type
3.Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete 
  Expression
after @Override
              public void onClick (View v){
              viewPager.setCurrentItem (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1); //or -1 to go previous
}

Comment: i changed R.id.your_viewpager_id () as R.id.activity_main_viewpager is this correct? or should it be R.id.activity_main_viewpager()?
and the error was gone but the one error still remains bt.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener () says View.onClickListener cannot be resolved to a type

Also where do we call the the page i intend to open on button click?

Comment: Try change to, View.OnClickListener() and yes is this correct. I'm unable to test codes because I dont have a computer right now.

Comment: On changing gives me 2 error
1.Button bt = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.button1); says Unreachable code
2.viewPager.setCurrentItem (viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1); says 
Multiple markers at this line
- Cannot refer to a non-final variable viewPager inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: Hmmm.. add a ' final ' attribute before ViewPager viewPager = ... The whole piece of code should be right  before " return root

Comment: ok there is no more error but i do one question where am i calling the page i want to see after clicking the button? The code as of now open the second fragment but i want to open completely another xml page or a class